# Contemporary approaches to kashrut of dates

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, agriculture, bugs, fruits

What are contemporary approaches regarding dealing with bug infestation of dates? Do Kashrut agencies (e.g. the Orthodox Union) regularly inspect crops to determine infestation levels? And if so, what are the statistics used to be lenient (*miut she'eino matzuy*)? I keep finding insects in Medjool dates (Mehadrin brand from Israel) that I get at Costco: its packaging has an OU but does not indicate a need for checking.

Comment: what about classical opinions?

Comment: Dried figs also encounter the same problem, and they're usually worse. The OU certification clarifies that the processing itself was kosher and sufficient for standard use. It in no way gaurantees that there are no insects of any kind in the product. That would be pretty much impossible.

Comment: Even assuming they're not guaranteeing that there are no insects, are they saying that there is no chiyyuv bedikah because they have ascertained in advance that the infestation level does not reach miut hamatzuy/muchzak b'tolaim or are they just assuming their certification doesn't imply any achrayus on their part?

Comment: The certification just shows that the processing was consistent with kosher requirements, not that the insects are bug free. The only time certification means the latter is where by default the object is kosher but subject to infestation, I.e.: bagged salad, frozen broccoli, etc.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky So does that mean they are certifying that you don't have a halachik obligation to check the dates? Also, what are you basing this on?

Comment: No. You still will have to check the dates and figs. Many organizations specifically state this. This all is coming from my experience working in a Kashrus organization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most people who rely e.g. on the OU assume the symbol means the food contained is kosher as is. Shouldn't they have halachik achrayus to specify explicitly on the packaging if/when that is not the case. Also, why then do they not certify other infestation-prone products, such as bagged romaine? And do they say this explicity anywhere? It sounds like a real michshol if these certified fruits are muchzak (and arguablyeven if they are not if people should realize and stop while eating the occasioanl bad one but dont b/c of the OU)...

Comment: Personally, I check the first three dates I take out of the package. If there are no bugs, I rely on the chazakah that they are all bug-free, lechatchila, although I usually check regardless